# Can I Invert a function to eliminate a divide by zero error?

Tags: elementary-functions

I'm working on a spreadsheet to break down hourly cost of a salary employee, depending on billable hours.

So, his Daily cost is a constant, call it CS (for Consistant Salary). 
His total billable hours per day will be TH.
His per-job hours will be JH.

My function is (CS/TH)*JH.

If he spends no time on a job, i'd get a divide by zero error. Is there a way to invert this so instead of diving by zero i'm multiplying by One over something?

Comment: I do not understand the question. I see how JH might be 0, but you do not divide by it.

Comment: In your case, $CS$ and $TH$ are both non-zero constants, and the amount of time he spends on the job are $JH$, which can possibly be zero. So you never get a divide by zero error, since $TH \ne 0$.

Comment: I think in Excel you can just use an IF() to catch the case where TH = 0.

Comment: If he spends no time on a job JH is 0, not TH.  How is TH calculated.  And are you sure that function makes sense.

Comment: Yep, that's totally it - my formula is dumb - hooray for a second pair of eyes!